# Is there a way to link an external library from outside the project directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shared-libraries, external

I have a jquery library in my project but need to put it in linux /usr/share/js directory and not inside of my project directory.

Is there a way to do a linking in the index.html?

Including in the index.html:

```
   <script src="/usr/share/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

doesn't help, as it looks into my working dir and I don't have a 'usr' dir

/usr/share is in the root directory and not in my working one. I don't use any php or the stuff, is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: I'm not exactly following what you're trying to do, but [you could use jQuery hosted by Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) for speed and bandwidth benefits.

Comment: Are you running the Javascript on the server with node.js, or is this for a web client? Because web clients can only access the webserver's document root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to back out of the file you are currently in by using the `../` command which goes back one directory. Depending on how many files deep the `index.html` file is in your project, you may need more then one like so:

`<script src="../../../../usr/share/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This will direct you 4 files out of where your `index.html` file is located, you may need more or less depending just do some searching through your directories and adjust accordingly.

Comment: You can't back out of the webserver's document root this way.

Comment: He never mentioned it being a webserver, I assumed it was a simple school or practise project and he is learning so I gave the simple solution.

Comment: That's why I asked the question in my comment above before trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create symlinks for files like this, to allow access to serve from not your document root.
The web server is also needs to be configured to follow symlinks when serving.

More info for Apache:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html